# Unable to upgrade bash

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, updates, bash

everyone knows about bash vulnerability "CVE-2014-6271", I'm trying to update bash using below command.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

but i'm getting bash is already newest version.

```
Reading state information... Done
bash is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
```

and its still vulnerable for "CVE-2014-6271".

Comment: I doubt this is the reason, but have you tried running a full upgrade? It could be that your system is so out of date that you can't upgrade Bash until you've upgraded other things...

Comment: Why have you specified *both* 12.04 and 13.10?

Comment: Maybe you have automatic updates configured? Have you tried running the command `dpkg -s bash | grep Version` to determine your current version of Bash? If so, what is the output?